# mouseevent not working in java fx

Tags: gradle, javafx

I am making a Javafx application in  Gradle  using intelj
in groovy and java i wrote the FXml controller class in java   So here the error

```
    JFXHamburger h1 = new JFXHamburger();
    HamburgerSlideCloseTransition burgerTask = new 
    HamburgerSlideCloseTransition(h1);
    burgerTask.setRate(-1);
    h1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, (e)->{
   burgerTask.setRate(burgerTask.getRate()*-1);
    burgerTask.play();
  });
```

I did Same as in the Documentation i Get this MeSsasge

```
       Error:(31, 18) java: method addEventHandler in class   
      javafx.scene.Node cannot be applied to given types;
    required: javafx.event.EventType<T>,javafx.event.EventHandler<? 
       superT>
     found: int,(e)->{ bur[...](); }
      reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
(argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to javafx.event.EventType<T>)
```

Comment: What is JFXHamburger? What kind of node?

Comment: Look the Jfoenix Library  ( http://www.jfoenix.com)  Its a custom type of  button

Comment: If it's a button use ActionEvent not MouseEvent